# jQuery - Multiple Email Addresses in Input Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a form that would allow users to enter multiple email addresses in an input field.

By searching around the net I cam across this jQuery plugin:
http://t2a.co/blog/index.php/multiple-value-input-field-with-jquery/

```
(function( $ ){

     $.fn.multipleInput = function() {

          return this.each(function() {

               // create html elements

               // list of email addresses as unordered list
               $list = $('<ul />');

               // input
               var $input = $('<input type="text" />').keyup(function(event) {

                    if(event.which == 32 || event.which == 188) {
                         // key press is space or comma
                         var val = $(this).val().slice(0, -1); // remove space/comma from value

                         // append to list of emails with remove button
                         $list.append($('<li class="multipleInput-email"><span> ' + val + '</span></li>')
                              .append($('<a href="#" class="multipleInput-close" title="Remove" />')
                                   .click(function(e) {
                                        $(this).parent().remove();
                                        e.preventDefault();
                                   })
                              )
                         );
                         $(this).attr('placeholder', '');
                         // empty input
                         $(this).val('');
                    }

               });

               // container div
               var $container = $('<div class="multipleInput-container" />').click(function() {
                    $input.focus();
               });

               // insert elements into DOM
               $container.append($list).append($input).insertAfter($(this));

               // add onsubmit handler to parent form to copy emails into original input as csv before submitting
               var $orig = $(this);
               $(this).closest('form').submit(function(e) {

                    var emails = new Array();
                    $('.multipleInput-email span').each(function() {
                         emails.push($(this).html());
                    });
                    emails.push($input.val());

                    $orig.val(emails.join());

               });

               return $(this).hide();

          });

     };
})( jQuery );
```

I installed the plugin, below is a screenshot of my results:

[image]

**My Questions:**

How can we edit the plugin to make sure that the last value (email address) does not have a comma at the end?

Here is a Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/William3780/oL14dgqp/

And here is a link to the live install I am working on:  http://51146.com/free/refer-a-friend/  *please fill out the "Friends' Emails" field and submit the form to see the issue.

Your input is very much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: JsFiddle would be useful.

Comment: You have something like `tag` in the first image. So when you get this , separated values back to its form? Since I've created a **[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/866yxeoy/)** I could see that you get tag like UI once you click `,` and I found no other option to get it back to `,` separated values..

Comment: The problem should be `emails.push($input.val());`. It push an empty value to the array, it will be better to check the `input.val() != ""` then push it into the array.

Comment: You may see this example. https://jsfiddle.net/h3g3gLf8/ You can clearly see that it pushed an empty string into the array.

Comment: updated the question with a jsFiddle and a link to the live install.

Comment: https://github.com/berenceylan/multiMailInput this plugin would do the work.

Answer (score 1):

well changed little bit of your code standards but created a working multiple email input. Here are the codes

**HTML**

```
<div class="multiple-val-input">
    <ul>
        <input type="text">
        <span class="input_hidden"></span>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.multiple-val-input{
        height: auto;
        min-height: 34px;
        cursor: text;
    }
    .multiple-val-input ul{
        float: left;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .multiple-val-input ul li{
        list-style: none;
        float: left;
        padding: 3px 5px 3px 5px;
        margin-bottom: 3px;
        margin-right: 3px;
        position: relative;
        line-height: 13px;
        cursor: default;
        border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
        border-radius: 3px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #fff inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
        box-shadow: 0 0 2px #fff inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
        background-clip: padding-box;
        -webkit-touch-callout: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
        background-color: #e4e4e4;
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, color-stop(20%, #f4f4f4), color-stop(50%, #f0f0f0), color-stop(52%, #e8e8e8), color-stop(100%, #eee));
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f4f4f4 20%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e8e8e8 52%, #eee 100%);
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f4f4f4 20%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e8e8e8 52%, #eee 100%);
        background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #f4f4f4 20%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e8e8e8 52%, #eee 100%);
    }
    .multiple-val-input ul li a{
        display: inline;
        color: #333;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .multiple-val-input ul li a, .multiple-val-input ul li div{
        display: inline;
        margin-left: 3px;
    }
    .multiple-val-input input[type="text"]{
        float: left;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        height: 20px;
        min-width: 5px;
        width: 5px;
    }
    .multiple-val-input span.input_hidden{
        font-size: 14px;
        position: absolute;
        clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
    }
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('.multiple-val-input').on('click', function(){
            $(this).find('input:text').focus();
        });
        $('.multiple-val-input ul input:text').on('input propertychange', function(){
            $(this).siblings('span.input_hidden').text($(this).val());
            var inputWidth = $(this).siblings('span.input_hidden').width();
            $(this).width(inputWidth);
        });
        $('.multiple-val-input ul input:text').on('keypress', function(event){
            if(event.which == 32 || event.which == 44){
                var toAppend = $(this).val();
                if(toAppend!=''){
                    $('<li><a href="#">×</a><div>'+toAppend+'</div></li>').insertBefore($(this));
                    $(this).val('');
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
                return false;
            };
        });
        $(document).on('click','.multiple-val-input ul li a', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parents('li').remove();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

JSFiddle would be appreciated but if you are trying to remove a comma of last element of an array or array of items in a String. I can imagine a few approaches:

1) Regex

```
var lastCommaPatter = ",$";

var emails = "test@gmail.com, test2@gmail.com, test@gmail.com,";

email.replace(lastCommaPatter, "");
```

2) Coverting entire thing into a collection and remove the last blank element

```
var SEPARATOR = ",";

var emails = "test@gmail.com, test2@gmail.com, test@gmail.com,";

var emailsCollection = email.split(SEPARATOR);

var collectionSize = emailsCollection.length;

if(collectionSize > 0){

  array.splice(emailsCollection, collectionSize - 1);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, would you be so kind to show me how to implement your suggestion into the plugin?

Comment: You should tell me a specific section of your code where you want my code example wants to exist. Otherwise I cannot easily point out where you must implement this in your source code.